# function onsuccess(response) show the entire page on the hidden div

Tags: javascript, php, html

every time the images uploaded, it shows the entire page on the hidden div, like the screenshot shows

[the webpage before upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2gPR.png)
and
[after uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60ic2.jpg)
I feel there's something wrong in the script tag below, because if I delete the response variable, it won't show the duplicated page anymore, but also no more response, which is supposed to be shown on the page.

Any help will be appreciated!

here's the code:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="uploadimg" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6"><br />
                        <label class="col-md-4">Product thumbnail:</label><input type="file" name="thumb" id="thumb"/><br />
                        <label class="col-md-4">Profile picture01:</label><input type="file" name="file01"/><br />
                        <label class="col-md-4">Profile picture02:</label><input type="file" name="file02"/><br />
                        <label class="col-md-4">Profile picture03:</label><input type="file" name="file03"/><br />
                        <label class="col-md-4">Profile picture04:</label><input type="file" name="file04"/><br />
                        <label class="col-md-4">Farmer's photo:</label><input type="file" name="farmer"/><br /><br />

                        <input class="btn btn-warning btn-sm " type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"/><br /><br />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <div id="loader">
                            <center><img src="images/loading.gif" /></center>
                        </div>
                        <div id="onsuccessmsg"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function onsuccess(response){
        $("#loader").hide();
        $("#onsuccessmsg").html('</b><div id="msg">'+response+'</div>');
    }

    $("#uploadimg").on('submit',function(){
        $("#loader").show();
        var options={
        success: onsuccess
        };

    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i dont think it works the way you think it should. investigate the return value of an ajax post, and see what it actually returns.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your current code when ran attempts to load the same page that the script is called from.

Comment: Actually I found out I forgot to add exit; command in the included file, it is included on the top of the page, so it outputs all the html to the hidden div, thanks for reminding me to check the output!